# Rails: making sure after_create runs in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm having issues with getting Rspec to run my `after_create` hook.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_one :user_profile

  after_create :create_user_profile

  protected

  def create_user_profile
    self.user_profile = UserProfile.new(user: self)
    self.user_profile.save
  end
end
```

My UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar,
    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar,
    content_type: { content_type: "image/jpeg" }
end
```

My spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UserProfile, :type => :model do
  describe 'initial create' do
    before do
      @user = User.new(email: 'user@example.com',
                       password: 's3kr3t',
                       password_confirmation: 's3kr3t')
      @user.save
    end

    it 'should have profile' do
      expect(@user.user_profile).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Fails with error:

```
Failures:                                                                                                                              │~
                                                                                                                                       │~
  1) UserProfile initial create should have profile                                                                                    │~
     Failure/Error: expect(@user.user_profile).to be_valid                                                                             │~
     NoMethodError:                                                                                                                    │~
       undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass                                                                                      │~
     # ./spec/models/user_profile_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                 │~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the given code had multiple errors, most of which had to do with an invalid User model:

1. Devise expects a password to be 8 chars minimum (so my User model wasn't saved due to its invalidity).
2. I missed adding the 3 "confirmable" fields to the User model migration.
3. After migrating my User model, I needed to add a "confirmed_at" attribute to the instantiated User model.
4. My UserProfile model was also missing a "user_id" attribute in its migration.

Once I fixed these issues, the code worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe UserProfile, :type => :model do
  describe 'initial create' do
    let(:user) { User.new(email: 'user@example.com',
                       password: 's3kr3t',
                       password_confirmation: 's3kr3t') }

    it 'should have profile' do
      @user.save
      expect(@user.user_profile).to_not be_nil
    end

    it "shouldn't have valid profile if not saved" do
      expect(@user.user_profile).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: RSpec will dynamically match any predicate method (ending in `?`). You can see this from OP's error message, where it is failing when trying to call `valid?`

Comment: very interesting @zetetic - I wasn't aware.  Is this new behavior?

Comment: No, it has done that for a while. RSpec is the Rails of testing frameworks: lots of features to discover.